# Copy Contents of a Directory with Java

Tags: java, file, copy

In my Java program I have 2 paths (Strings) of 2 different directories.

I want a method to copy all the files from one directory to the other. 
(just the contents, not the folder).

How can I do that?

Comment: Please have a look at the classes File, Files or the Apache jar FileUtils.

Comment: Can use Apache Commons FileUtils. Pls check my answer

Answer (score 1):

Make a class that extends `SimpleFileVisitor<Path>` and override its methods. `visitFile` should copy the file to the new directory and the `VisitDirectory` methods should just continue down the tree. Then use the new class with `Files.walkFileTree`.

Answer (score 0):

Can use

> org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils;

```
Collection getAllFilesThatMatchFilenameExtension(String directoryName, String extension)
{
  File directory = new File(directoryName);
  return FileUtils.listFiles(directory, new WildcardFileFilter(extension), null);
}
```

loop through the collection and call

```
   FileUtils.copyFileToDirectory(file, destinationDir);
```